# Popup dialog box closes on submit first time but not if used more than once

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've got a popup box with a submit form.  The first time I use it on a visit to a site, it closes on submit and works appropriately.  If I use it a second time, the submission works and the page updates but the box stays visible.  Here's the code:

```
<head>
    <script>  
    $(function() {    
        $( "#dialog" ).dialog();  
        $( "#Add").click(function(){
             $( "#dialog" ).dialog("close"); 
        });
    });  
</script>
</head>
    <body> <div id="dialog" title="Select Item">
        Position <%= @i %><br /><br />   
       <%= form_tag( {:controller => :cabinets, :action => :update_device_position, :position => @i , :id => @cabinet.id }, :remote => true) do %>
            <td>
                <%= select_tag :position_name, options_for_select(@selection_list) %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%= hidden_field_tag 'position', @i %>
                <%= submit_tag "Add" ,:id=> "Add", :class => "btn" %>

            </td>
        <% end %>
       </div>  
    </body>
```

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: can you post what the final output looks like.  I dont see anything specifically wrong with the code.  Perhaps the final output will give better insight.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "final output."  There are no errors and no logs in the Rails Console when the button is pressed.  The box stays up and the ruby code runs as it should.

Comment: sorry, I will try to be more clear.  The code you pasted was from some type of templating engine.  looks like asp rendering or EJS.  In any case, this is prerendered content.  The code I am looking for is what you would see in a browser.  You would need to render the page normally, open up your browsers developer tools and copy the final code here.